# Google maps utilization in website

Tags: django, maps

I'm currently developping a website with Django where users has an attribute "address". So I need to know each user's address.
For the moment, i'm using google maps API in front end. So i save an address (Charfield) in my database, but i'm afraid of "dirty" address.

Do you have any idea of how check the reality of addresses user register in back end ? :)

Thank you very much  !

Comment: If you need the exact address you´ll need to ask the user explicitly.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing, i let him write his own address in a specific input with the google maps API autocompletion. But how can I prevent him from entering smth witch is not an address (for example i don't want him to entering "New York" which is not a valid address. 
And I would like to check this in front and back end (for user who do not have javascript) 
Thank you :)